# How to include php page has my class

Tags: php, class, include

I have a problem while including my own php class page from its server.

I hosted my php classes page like http://my.website.com/phpclasses.php

and tried to call it from another host such as:

```
<?php 
include ("http://my.website.com/phpclasses.php");
?>
```

By the way, the php class page has a class named 'test'
and activated in it by this variable, here is a quick view about it:

phpclasses.php

```
class test{
somefunctions();
somefunctions();
}
$test = new test();
```

I requested this page from another website like this:

anotherwebsite.php:

```
 $newclass = new test();
 $newclass->somefunctions();
```

Notice that i've activated the class twice, once in its page, and again in the another website, but failed and returns nothing.

How could it work?

Comment: Don't include from a URL.  It isn't going to work anyway, unless you're echoing out your PHP code...

Comment: php is server side code, including from an URL will only return a processed page. which is probably a blank page

Comment: In my opinion it is bad, but any way you i think you can use eval to evaluate the code you download from another webpage, echoing it... but i repeat it's a really bad and an unusual coding behavior.

Comment: Is it on the same server?  If so, just use `include ("/phpclasses.php");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to include over HTTP unless your printing PHP Code to the browser. Otherwise it will not work.

It's best to include locally:

*Class.php*

```
 class Test{
        public function __construct(){
            return TRUE;
        }            
 }
```

*index.php*

```
include "Class.php";

$Class = new Test();
```

Both files are located on the same server (same directory).. if including in other directories, add correct path to the file:

```
 include "/Core/Class.php";
```

Being interpreted as

> / - Root Directory
>
> Core - Sub directory
>
> Class.php - File name

Comment: including over HTTP will only return what is printed to the webpage.  I guess you could create some form of CURL Request with a secure hash & only with that hash on the receiving server matching up, will print out RAW PHP Code.. but there would be a more viable method to do such a thing.. just what i'd do (after correctly securing with access restrictions and such)

Comment: the issue is that i have my php classes page hosted on a server and i need to request it FROM ANOTHER SERVER not only in the same server, i mean to request the php classes page everywhere, and the class has functions and i want to pass a parameter $var and call the class and use the function and pass my own parameter to echo it or else, i mean like this:

class.php:

class test{
   public function f1($var1) {
       return $var1." ".$var1;
      }
    }

In another server, i do this:

    include ("website.com/class.php");
    $newvar = new test();
    $text = $newvar->f1("Hello");

Comment: @nael_d So, your looking curl requests to communicate with the API on the remote server, to return a string/number to the local server? If that's not what your looking for, then you've lost me

Comment: i want to use the class and call the function after passing the needed parameter to return a string value, like:

$text = "Hi";
$new = new test();
$var = $new->my_own_echo($text); // will return "Hi"


It's a simple function but i think that you've got me

Comment: @nael_d Then CURL is what your looking for.. This question title is not going to attract the corect attention. research into CURL and other form of Contacting Remote servers via HTTP, and if your still stuck after that. Come back to StackOverflow

Comment: So, please do you have any simple reference I could return to study it well then apply it on my own projects? I don't have an enough knowledge about it, just i heared about it by chance but didn't care.